# Excel power query folder path

Tags: excel, powerquery

I’m really new to excel power queries, but finding it really useful.

My question is this, when I have created a table to pull data from 20 or so worksheets in a folder. My source is

```
Source = Folder.Files{“\\myserver\folders\stuff\data WC 06.07.2020”)
```

I have no control over naming this data folder and the name keeps getting changed, so obviously it throws up an error each week and I have to manually go in an change the query.

Is there a way for the date part to be ignored and it still pull from the correct folder?

Thanks if you can help

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use a variable, and put the path name there

Give cell a range name, like **DirVariable** in excel and put your location in there, like

```
\\myserver\folders\stuff\data WC 06.07.2020\
```

Then change the powerquery code to use that rangename

```
Source = Folder.Files(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DirVariable"]}[Content]{0}[Column1])
```

alternately, put  just the date in the variable

```
06.07.2020
```

and have the code pre-append the path

```
Source = Folder.Files("\\myserver\folders\stuff\data WC "&Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DirVariable"]}[Content]{0}[Column1])
```

If you want, you can attempt to look for most recently modified excel file within any path starting with \\myserver\folders\stuff, and then grab the directory associated with that file, and use that. It would be something like

```
let directory = "\\myserver\folders\stuff\",
Source=Folder.Files(directory),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Folder Path] <> directory and Text.Start([Extension],4)=".xls"),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Date modified", Order.Descending}}),
MostRecent=  #"Sorted Rows"{0}[#"Folder Path"],
Source2 =Folder.Files(MostRecent)
in Source2
```

Comment: Thanks very much HR, just to be clear. I could create a blank worksheet in that folder, place the date in a cell and name it, and power query will ignore all future date changes to the folder?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the power query tsble is in a completely different folder as it cannot be in the same folder as the worksheets it’s pulling data from

Comment: Is there a way of saying:

Source = Folder.Files("\\myserver\folders\stuff\data WC "&**.**.****])

So it doesn’t look for a particular date?

Comment: No, This is code for the spreadsheet that reads that directory. It saves you from manually changing the powerquery code each time, and  instead you would change the path or filename in the variable. Nothing can stop you from needing to update the code, unless you plan to read in a file that contains that info in it from somewhere

Comment: edited answer above to provide sample code that would look for the subdirectory with most recently modified *.xl* file in and then do a Folder.Files on that one